# How does Hōō Maniwa regain his left arm?

Tags: katanagatari

When we are first introduced to [Hōō Maniwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Katanagatari_characters#Maniwa_Ninja_Corps_Heads), he cuts off his own left arm to prove his intent.  I expected it to come back, and about halfway through episode 8, we see it has returned.  Although, that may not be a bird-like appendage, but may be some other kind of animal.

How does Hōō Maniwa regain his left arm?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it a transplanted arm

> *Ninpō: Danzaien* - This technique allows Hōō to decapitate anyone with a swing of his arm, as shown when **he severs his own left arm** to form an alliance with Togame, **though he regains the use of said lost arm shortly after from Kawauso Maniwa's corpse.** This ability was originally called Namagoroshi by the Aioi Clan, the ninja clan murdered by the Maniwa.

Source: [Hōō > Maniwa > Abilities (second dot point)](http://katanagatari.wikia.com/wiki/H%C5%8D%C5%8D_Maniwa#Abilities)

now looking at [Kawauso Maniwa](http://katanagatari.wikia.com/wiki/Kawauso_Maniwa) we can see that he would more likely fit that arm

[image: Kawauso Maniwa]

and going by what is described for Volume 6

> He is willingly killed by Hōō Maniwa in order to maintain the alliance between the Maniwa Ninja Corps and Togame.

this gives Hōō the perfect opportunity to get a new arm. also it's been a while since I've seen the series but if i recall correctly Hōō shows to have Kawauso's Kiroku Tadori Ninpō as being the reason why

> Hōō is possessed by Kiki Shikizaki, a result of the Kiroku Tadori Ninpō being used on Dokutō Mekki